# Strange iOS memory allocation behavior

Tags: iphone, memory, ios4

I noticed quite a strange thing while trying to allocate a lot of memory on my iPhone 3G running iOS 4.2.1.

When I call `malloc(512 * 1024)` in a loop it returns a valid pointer for about 1500 times after which I get a `NULL` and

```
app(2032,0x3e7518b8) malloc: *** mmap(size=524288) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
```

It surprised me, since I think my iPhone doesn't 750 MB of RAM.  Then I added a `memset` after the `malloc` and it brought the number of allocations down to 120, which makes much more sense.

Here's the super-simple code that I used:

```
for (int i = 1; ; ++i)
{
    void *p = malloc(512 * 1024);
    NSLog(@"%d %p", i, p);
    memset(p, 0, 512 * 1024);
}
```

I though iPhone didn't have any virtual memory system that could explain behavior similar to this.  What would be a reasonable explanation for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On iOS (and many other systems), a call to `malloc()` doesn't actually allocate memory. It requests memory from the OS/kernel, but the request is not satisfied until the memory is written to (e.g. with `memset()`.) This allows for greater efficiency in the system's memory management, but it can result in misleading `malloc()` behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone definitely has a virtual memory system. What it's missing is the ability to page memory out to disk. In other words, it's missing swap space.